# handling a null get in res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a nodejs app built like this:

```
app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', function (req, res, next) {
    var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ' + req.params.ent_cust_id;
    console.log('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id =' + req.params.ent_cust_id);
    client.execute(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return next (err);
    var row = result.rows[0];
    //Response
    res.json({ent_cust_id: req.params.ent_cust_id, name: row.get('offers')});
});
});
```

but it causes node to shut down like this when the results of the array come back empty...

```
[root@ip-10-205-116-141 cassapi]# /usr/local/bin/node app.js
Example app listening at http://0.0.0.0:3030
Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id =1106667844
events.js:87
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at /home/ec2-user/cassapi/app.js:16:14
    at readCallback (/home/ec2-user/cassapi/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:195:5)
    at Connection.invokeCallback (/home/ec2-user/cassapi/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/connection.js:567:5)
    at Connection.handleResult (/home/ec2-user/cassapi/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/connection.js:507:8)
    at ResultEmitter.emit (events.js:120:17)
    at ResultEmitter.each (/home/ec2-user/cassapi/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:437:17)
    at ResultEmitter._write (/home/ec2-user/cassapi/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:421:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:303:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:290:5)
    at ResultEmitter.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:219:11)
```

I've tried to adjust app.get like this to check to see if the array is empty:

```
app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', function (req, res, next) {
        var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ' + req.params.ent_cust_id;
        console.log('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id =' + req.params.ent_cust_id);
        client.execute(query, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next (err);
        var row = result.rows[0];
            if (row.get('ent_cust_id') = '') {
                res.send('ent_cust_id: ' + req.params.ent_cust_id + ' not found. Not all data is loaded.');
        } else {
            var row = result.rows[0];
                //Response
                res.json({ent_cust_id: req.params.ent_cust_id, accts: row.get('accts'), offers: row.get('offers')});
        }
        });
 });
```

I'm thinking I need an if statement to check if no records were returned in results.rows and then do an res.send. I tried that but the same behavior still occures. How do I find out if no records were returned?

EDIT:

Made code changes in the first part...pasted in the wrong code...clarified question too.

Comment: How is `app` being defined?

Comment: You should check that `row` in `var row = result.rows[0];` is not undefined as it would be if `result.rows.length === 0` (you could use that as the guard.) as i think that it is the `row.get` not `app.get` that is failing.

Comment: yeah, I believe its failing because the `ent_cust_id` entered in as the parameter is returing no records, I check this by directly putting the query in the database. `ent_cust_id` that are found in the database, the node id works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact behavior of your client.execute(sql, callback(err, result)) function.  You just have to test for what it returns on no results.

Ordinarily a callback from a database query will pass an empty array as the result if there are no results.  So if you handle the case where result.length==0, you will no longer be trying to reference result[i].row.get on rows that no longer exist.

Although it is not the cause of this particular problem, you also want to escape your SQL queries.  There is really no downside and it significantly increases your application security.

Comment: not sure if I'm trying this right but would it be `if (row.length = 0)` to check if an empty array came back?

Comment: Two equal signs for comparison, one for assignment--and you want to check the result, not the potentially nonexistent row.  Your code is client.execute(query, function (err, result)) -- so if client.execute works like most database query functions, the result of the query goes into result if there is no error.  You want to test if (result.length==0).

Comment: doing  `if (row.length==0)` { ` shuts down node and gives me this error... `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at /home`...

Comment: got it working! did `if (result.rows.length==0) {` and now it goes to res.send on an empty array...

Answer (score 0):

Let's attack the problem. First, your error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

This is `node` telling you that you wrote `<object>.get`, but when it tried to access the `get` property, it found that `<object>` was `undefined`.

Even more so, it's telling you where it happened:

```
/home/ec2-user/cassapi/app.js:16:14
```

Go to that file, and take a look at line `16`. It's probably one of the 2 you posted:

```
app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', ...)
// or
row.get('offers')
```

So, you think `app` or `row` are objects with a `get()` method, but one of them must be `undefined`. This can happen for 2 reasons:

- The `app` has a value of `undefined`-- was it assigned? Is it coming from another function? Did that function forget to `return`?
- The row variable, assigned to `result.rows[0]`, is `undefined`. Does `result.rows` have a `[0]` element? Could the array be empty?

Check the part where you create the `app` object, and the `results` you obtain `.row[0]` from. Use `console.log` to see their values. The error should be easy to spot.

Comment: yes...I know the array is coming back empty and thats what I was trying to check for in the if statement. I just don't know the syntax for checking (or if the statement is even right) if the array is coming back empty.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//in your require, consider using below:
//var body-parser = require('body-parser'); // after installing with npm. I recommend globally installing
//app.use(body-parser()); //make sure you add this to initialize body parser after installing it.  *NOTE: If using node with express 4.~ this is deprecated so ignore.

app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', function (req, res, next) {
        //Your code: var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?' [req.params.ent_cust_id];
  /* Above, should probably include a plus sign between "?'" and "[req.params.....]; as below:   */
        var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?' + [req.params.ent_cust_id];
        //Another typo detailed below
  //Your code: consolelog('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?');
  console.log('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?');
  /* Also, at this point you want to be logging your full query var, not your manually entered string value so type this as below:   */
  console.log(query); // shows your query, not your manually typed string.
  //There really shouldn't ever be an issue with your manually typed query unless you need it surrounded in quotes.
  //For greater clarification, whatever you're calling client below should be defined and expanded upon with an example.  
  
  /* In this code snippet, I typically always send the response first, if there is NOT an err liks so: if(!err){ //do the client's stuff first, else (if there's an error, does not need to be defined) { //do whatever else }  Handling errors after it adds a small bit of speed to your process and reduces a step if you get a valid response and leaves error responding to secondary processing under the expectation you won't encounter an error  */
    client.execute(query, function (err, result) {
    if(!err) { //do your client stuff first if no error then return next.
    } else { console.log(err); return next} ; //No conditional needed for the error, because you've gotten here due to your code not working.
      
    //if (err) return next (err);
    var row = result.rows[0];
    //Response
    res.json({ent_cust_id: req.params.ent_cust_id, name: row.get('offers')});  /* Here you're responding with a JSON object as if you were querying a large JSON file.  You may want to consider using res.send with and application/json response type.  */
      
});
});
```

```html
<div> For additional explanation on routing, you may want to look at express documentation here: <a href="http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.json">express res.json</a></div>

<p> Also, make sure you're requiring body-parser in node so you can interpret incoming routes! </p>

<code> npm install -g body-parser </code>
```